# How do I sum values from different rows with matching columns from a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

So, my problem is the following: I have a DataGridView with 4 different columns (Name, Group, Value, Date), and I have 6 distinct textboxes for all the 6 groups (let´s suppose a, b, c, d ,e and f)

So my goal is to add the values from the column value, from rows with equal group

For example:

(DataGridView info):

```
Pear / a / 6 / 10-12-2016
Apple / b / 7 / 10-12-2016
Banana / a / 8 / 10-12-2016
```

The result should be the sum of the row "Pear" with the row "Banana", resulting on 14 (6+8), because they have the same group (a), and the result should be displayed on the TextBox corresponding to the "Group a".

Hope you can help me :D

Comment: Is the DataGridView data bound, and if so, what is the underlying data structure?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you try something and it didn't work? Some effort on your part is expected. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: The problem is that I am linda new to c#, and I can't code alone yet, I need guides from YouTube and from other networks like StackOverflow

Comment: If you say you're new to programming, then directly asking how to do what you want to achieve is the wrong approach. There are too many ways to solve this, from common loops to Linq, and you might not be able to understand all the solutions or why do them work. Split your problem into smaller problems (how do I loop through all the rows of a DataGridView? -how do I read the values from the cells of a DataGridView? -how do I compare those values with something else? -how do I sum values and store the result?)  and solve them one by one, then combine all into one solution.